# supported screens in android

Tags: android, screen

I would like to prevent users downloading my app with devices smaller then 7 inches.

I know I can define supports-screens in the Android Manifest, but this only is regarding the density. I mean a small device with a high density goes into the same class as a large screen with low density.

I also know that I could disable specific devices in the app properties on GooglePlay.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

a snapshot of the answer:

```
Explicitly declare in the manifest which screen sizes your application supports
By declaring which screen sizes your application supports, you can ensure that only devices with the screens you support can download your application. Declaring support for different screen sizes can also affect how the system draws your application on larger screens—specifically, whether your application runs in screen compatibility mode.
To declare the screen sizes your application supports, you should include the <supports-screens> element in your manifest file.
```

details of the `<supports-screen>` can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).

Comment: Do you have a practical example on how to define this in the Android-Manifest. Perhabs I do not understand because of the lack in english. My guess is, that you only can define the screensize regarding the density. But I like to prevent users from downloading with screen lesser then 7 inches.